# Função MAP em Lista de Dicionários

Tags: python, expressões-lambda, map

Aplique a função map na lista de emprestimos para extrair os valores da chave valor_emprestimos na lista valor_emprestimos_lista. Faça também a conversão de str para float.

emprestimos: [{'id_vendedor': '104271', 'valor_emprestimos': '448.0', 'quantidade_emprestimos': '1', 'data': '20161208'}, {'id_vendedor': '21476', 'valor_emprestimos': '826.7', 'quantidade_emprestimos': '3', 'data': '20161208'}, {'id_vendedor': '87440', 'valor_emprestimos': '313.6', 'quantidade_emprestimos': '3', 'data': '20161208'}, {'id_vendedor': '15980', 'valor_emprestimos': '-8008.0', 'quantidade_emprestimos': '6', 'data': '20161208'}, {'id_vendedor': '215906', 'valor_emprestimos': '2212.0', 'quantidade_emprestimos': '5', 'data': '20161208'}, {'id_vendedor': '33696', 'valor_emprestimos': '2771.3', 'quantidade_emprestimos': '2', 'data': '20161208'}, {'id_vendedor': '33893', 'valor_emprestimos': '2240.0', 'quantidade_emprestimos': '3', 'data': '20161208'}, {'id_vendedor': '214946', 'valor_emprestimos': '-4151.0', 'quantidade_emprestimos': '18', 'data': '20161208'}, {'id_vendedor': '123974', 'valor_emprestimos': '2021.95', 'quantidade_emprestimos': '2', 'data': '20161208'}, {'id_vendedor': '225870', 'valor_emprestimos': '4039.0', 'quantidade_emprestimos': '2', 'data': '20161208'}]

##### Minha Resposta

valor_emprestimos_lista = map(lambda valor_emprestimo : float(emprestimos[:]['valor_emprestimos']), emprestimos)
print(list(valor_emprestimos_lista))

##### Erro

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 print(list(valor_emprestimos_lista)) # [448.0, 826.7, ..., 4039.0]

in (valor_emprestimo)
----> 1 valor_emprestimos_lista = map(lambda valor_emprestimo : float(emprestimos[:]['valor_emprestimos']), emprestimos)

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow. Sua publicação parece ter alguns problemas, nós somos um site de perguntas e respostas, e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045)

Answer (score -2):

No contexto que tu tá usando, `emprestimos[:]` é a "mesma coisa" que `emprestimos` ainda que sejam tecnicamente objetos distintos porque retorna uma cópia da lista inteira, então `emprestimos[:]['valor_emprestimos']` está tentando acessar a chave 'valor_emprestimos' de **emprestimos**, da mesma forma que se tu tivesse acessando `emprestimos['valor_emprestimos']`, onde `emprestimos` é uma lista de dicionários, e não um dicionário, e portanto não tem a chave 'valor_emprestimos'.

O que o erro diz é que listas deveriam ser acessadas por posição, como em `emprestimos[0]`, `emprestimos[1]`, `emprestimos[-1]`, etc. Sendo uma lista de dicionários, `emprestimos[0]['valor_emprestimos']` é o que tu realmente quer, daí a necessidade de usar uma solução como `map()` pra iterar sobre a lista inteira aplicando uma função.

Além disto, o `map()` aplica uma função a uma lista, então a tua função lambda usa a variável `valor_emprestimo` como um item da lista `emprestimo`, e portanto na primeira iteração, `valor_emprestimo` é igual a `emprestimos[0]`. Ou seja, `valor_emprestimo['valor_emprestimos']` vai retornar o resultado esperado porque é equivalente a `emprestimos[0]['valor_emprestimos']`.

```py
valor_emprestimos_mapa = map(lambda valor_emprestimo : float(valor_emprestimo['valor_emprestimos']), emprestimos)
valor_emprestimos_lista = list(valor_emprestimos_mapa)
print(valor_emprestimos_lista)
```

Neste caso é possível replicar a funcionalidade deste mapa, já que a função pretendida não é complexa, com compreensão de listas desta forma:

```py
print([float(emprestimo['valor_emprestimos']) for emprestimo in emprestimos])
```

Comment: Foi por isso que eu usei as aspas, o que eu quis dizer é que não tem razão pra usar essa expressão naquele contexto, e é por isso que ele está recebendo aquele erro. Dentro do contexto dele, vai ser a mesma coisa,mesmo que sejam objetos diferentes.

Comment: mudei a resposta pra esclarecer porque é a mesma coisa neste contexto

Comment: Se quer positivos tem muita coisa que melhorar, começa pela pergunta. Ela realmente tem que ser uma pergunta pois o conjunto perguntas e respostas não é inicialmente destinado para eu, você ou o autor da pergunta. Tudo que nós produzimos é para ser consumido por ferramentas de automação, seja Motores de Busca, AIs de auto completar código, AIs de auto programação, NPL,......... o foco não é o helpdesk pessoal o nosso foco é o futuro e o coletivo.

Comment: Obrigado amigo. Me ajudou bastante

Answer (score -2):

Eu fiz assim:

valor_emprestimos_lista = list(map(lambda emprestimo:
float(emprestimo['valor_emprestimos']), emprestimos))

print(valor_emprestimos_lista)